# Desktop Screen Edges No Longer Work?

Tags: updates, kubuntu, 17.10

After the last set of updates for Kubuntu 17.10, screen edges no longer works. I use a large (8, although some people might not consider this a large number) number of virtual desktops. One way I organize my workspace is to use the screen edges to show the desktop grid by moving the cursor into the top left corner, and this displays the desktop grid.

I tried restarting plasmashell, and then tried restarting the computer, but this didn't seem to resolve the problem. I also attempted to clear the settings in system settings, and then reset all the setings to what I wanted them to be, but no luck.

**What Happens:**

When I move over to the corner that has the screen effect, it imply doesn't do anything.

How can I resolve this?

**Edit 0:**

I should add that the default shortcut for `Show Desktop Grid: Ctl + F8` doesn't work either. Upon pressing `Ctl + F8` nothing happens.

Comment: are you using Wayland or Xorg session?

Comment: @ravery Running `env | grep -i wayland` return nothing. From this, I assume I'm running Xorg

Comment: Another way: `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` and are you using the kubuntu-backports ppa?

Comment: @DKBose That gave `/usr/share/xsessions/plasma x11
`, and no, I'm not using backports.